# How to populate a form with a populated Entity in symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have an EntityType with an embedded EntityType collection. When I create a form and pass an empty instance of the related object everything works as expected.

However if I populate an object using Doctrine and pass this to the form I get a viewData error.

I have put alot more detail in a [***previous question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750983/cannot-set-form-with-populated-entity-object-get-the-forms-view-data-is-expecte)  and the answer given to this put me on the right path - almost.

It seems using @parameter annotation will fill the blanks in for me.

I would like to understand how I can do this myself in code e.g sudo code:

populatedEntity = Doctrine->getEntity

form = (entityType,populatedEntity)

Doing it this way throws an viewData error. I have set the class_data in the EntityType to that of the Entity

This works:

emptyEntity = new Entity

form = (entityType,emptyEntity)

Comment: could you please fix the code in your question? And give some more detailed information like the error message / ask a concrete question?

Comment: This relates to the question you started to answer for me yesterday (see the link). Your answer was really helpful but I still dont have a grasp on how to do the basics of passing a populated Entity to a form. I didnt want to get into the nuts and bolts of the code but wanted a more general understandig to see if my approach to Symfony forms is correct i.e can I pass a populated Entity to a form and have the data populate through to the html? I have read the docs but cant seem to get a hndle on how to do this?